# change auto filter operator in xtragrid

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, xtragrid

How can I modify the default filter operator the DevExpress.Xtragrid.gridcontrol 
When I try to filter a string column by a value, the default way to filter is "Beggins with".
I would like to filter by "Contains", so that I can take all the rows withe the specific value in the columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Just set the [OptionsColumnFilter.AutoFilterCondition](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsOptionsColumnFilter_AutoFilterConditiontopic) property to `Contains`for the specific column.